# Rapsberry pi getting an 404 ERROR while upgrading

Tags: raspberry-pi, flir

I tried to install the FLIR Lepton library on Raspberry Pi zero w but as i was the[FLIR Lepton](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/raspberrypi_video) (sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools)in pi this error message show up

```
Get:105 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf vlc-plugin-video-splitter armhf 3.0.12-0+deb10u1+rpt1 [140 kB]
Get:106 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf vlc-plugin-visualization armhf 3.0.12-0+deb10u1+rpt1 [142 kB]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror1.ku.ac.th/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_10.3+rpi1+deb10u8_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: ---------]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror1.ku.ac.th/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6+rpi1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: ---------]
```

this is an example there are 100+ line of these

as i trying to troubleshoot the error i found out that not just the upgrading that has an error. there is the same 404 error with `upgrade` and `update` as well. Is there any problem with the raspberry pi or maybe my internet?

PS. The raspberry pi is brand new, and i use ssh to connect to the raspberry pi

PS.2 I just reinstall the OS the result is the same

PS.3 I randomly choose the link in the terminal. it direct me in to the ERROR 404 web as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer is that there are some problem in mirror1.ku what i need to do is go to

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then add

`deb http://mirror1.ku.ac.th/raspbian  buster main contrib non-free rpi`

in the last line then its all fine. the reason is that my raspberry is redirecting into the wrong directory and that's the reason for 404 error

Answer (score 0):

`1` . Erase the sdcard you are using (`if it is not carrying some data you don't want to lose`)
`2`. Download a previous version of pios or upgrade the current one

Comment: as I mention above that the raspberry pi is brand new and so is the sd card so erasing it would help. i even done it already too. your second solution i just done it the result is the same after I `sudo apt update` as a first command

Answer (score 0):

This is because your raspberry is not updated, still pointing to old repos. For fix it you should update it, you can follow the instructions here. After that all work as expected for me and not more 404. raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html

Answer (score 0):

A fastest and safest way is: installing a new LTS OS rather than trying to fix a lot of issues on that obsolete/outdated raspbian OS. Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi is the best choice (very long time support). It takes around 5-8 minutes to download and install the OS.

- **Backup important data on your Pi.**
- Use your laptop/PC, download 1GB Ubuntu server image.
- Use application `Raspberry Pi Imager` to burn the image to your SD card with pre-configured wifi, SSH key, username/password.
- Plug SD card to your Pi and enjoy.